# In bash script how to use cli argument as a variable for mysql query and capture result?

Tags: mysql, bash

With this SQL query `film_name` is to be set with value of `$1` coming from command line argument. And of course I want to capture the result any ideas? I want to do something like this

```
result=$(mysql myapp -B --column-names=0  -e "select film_id from films where film_name='$1'")
```

But this does not work. I think `bash` has a problem with variables in the SQL body

Comment: as a variable in the same bash script

Comment: I want to use $1. Its coming from the script argument

Comment: How are you passing the argument to the script `script.sh filmname`?

Comment: Did you try enclosing the variable in {} ? eg  `..where film_name='{$1}'`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like the below, using "set" :

```
myarg=$1
mysql -h<host> -u<user> -p<password> <<"SQL"
set @my_arg='$myarg';
select film_id from films where film_name=@my_arg;
SQL
```